# Physically move Hard drive, with Ubuntu 18.04 on it, to another PC

Tags: upgrade, hard-drive, hardware

I would like to move my physical hard drive, on my Dell Optiplex CX620, with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. To my Dell Optiplex 7010.

I'd like to review procedures first if any before I attempt this. I have searched on Google and YouTube but found nothing.

Comment: The *procedure* is not difficult: 1) Backup your data. 2) Have an LiveUSB installer handy. 3) Move the disk. 4) Ensure your BIOS sees the new drive and boots from it. 5) Try booting. What to do when you encounter an expected problem is the hard part. Example: If I recall correctly, CX620 uses an IDE Hard drive. But 7010 has no IDE connection...it uses SATA instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.